# wrap_content to largest?

Tags: android

have a TableLayout that has a bunch of row that look like this:

```
<TableRow android:id="@+id/ROW_CHOOSE_ANSWER_1">

  <Button android:id="@+id/BUTTON_CHOOSE_ANSWER_1"
         style="@style/cue_minor"  
         android:clickable="true"
            android:cursorVisible="false"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="45"
            android:layout_width="1dip"
            android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
            />

     <Button android:id="@+id/BUTTON_CHOOSE_ANSWER_2"
            style="@style/cue_minor"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:cursorVisible="false"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="45"
            android:layout_width="1dip"
            android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
            />

</TableRow>
```

the current behavior is such that if the text of the first button wraps to the second line, the height of the button will be larger. this is good. however, the other button, if it does not have that much text will be smaller.

i would like to have both buttons have the same height --- which is the maximum height required by the button with the largest amount of text.

can i do this with layout tags or would i need to do this manually through code somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Set `android:minHeight="30dip";` or some value in both of them

Answer (score 0):

just try giving the height as `fill_parent`... Hope this will work....